# State Inside SliverPersistentHeader?

Tags: flutter

I'm attempting to use a SliverPersistentHeader to show/hide a calendar whose state needs to be maintained. Per [Flutter's documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html), a SliverPersistentHeader is a Stateless widget. Is it possible to maintain the state of the calendar even though it's encompassed by the stateless SliverPersistentHeader?

The method "setState" is not defined in SliverPersistentHeader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who may have been interested in this question, I ended up replacing the SliverPersistentHeader with an AnimatedContainer, whose height was set either to 0 or "full height" depending on a boolean set by a GestureDetector swipe.

Answer (score 0):

I kept the `SliverPersistentHeader` but inside the `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` I just made a `StatefulWidget` for the child